# A "countable Zorn's lemma"?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is there something like a "countable Zorn's lemma" which is equivalent to the axiom of countable choice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not exactly. But there is one equivalent to Dependent Choice, the big brother of countable choice, and the principle most mathematicians think of when they think of countable choice.

> **Theorem.** The Principle of Dependent Choice is equivalent to the statement that every partial order has a maximal element or a countable chain.

The proof of this ranges from almost trivial to simple to "there's a small trick to remember", depending on how you define Dependent Choice.

Note, however, that the statement is not exactly the Zorn's Lemma condition, but it's not far from it: it omits the assumption "every chain which is finite has an upper bound". That is due to the fact that this is a theorem of $\sf ZF$, so it can be omitted. But if we want to generalize the equivalence, we need to bring it back. Which leads us to the following,

> **Theorem.** The Principle of Dependent Choice is equivalent to the statement: If $P$ is a partial order where every finite chain has an upper bound, then $P$ contains a countable chain or a maximal element.

Which can now be generalized to arbitrary cardinals.

> **Theorem.** The principle $\sf DC_\kappa$ is equivalent to the statement: If $P$ is a partial order that every chain of order-type $<\kappa$ has an upper bound, then $P$ has a maximal element or a chain of type $\kappa$.

These were proved by Wolk in the following paper

> *Wolk, Elliot S.*, [**On the principle of dependent choices and some forms of Zorn’s lemma**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1983-062-5), Can. Math. Bull. 26, 365-367 (1983). [ZBL0491.04005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0491.04005).